# Multiple inflated views in loop for

Tags: android, listview, view, inflate

I want to show several `ListView` views, each with its corresponding title in a `LinearLayout`.

I have a `LinearLayout`, I inflate a view to fill the title and `ListView` and add that view to the `LinearLayout` in a loop, but only one title and list appears (the first one).

I want the the view containing the title and the list view, to appear as many times as the for loop repeats.

Let me show you the code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//fragment_history: a layout with a LinearLayout inside called "main"

      View fragmentHistory = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

//I want to show a date, and all the transactions accomplished that date. With this two arrays, I pretend to loop by day, show the date as title and show the transactions of that day in the listview.

        allExpenses = dataExpenses.getAllExpenses();
        allDatesExpenses = dataExpenses.getAllDates();

// The LinearLayout inside the fragmentHistory layout 

        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) fragmentHistory.findViewById(R.id.main);       
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// I made a for loop, and I have two different dates. Two transactions in the first date, and one in the second day. But only the two transactions are been shown.

        for(int x = 0, y = allDatesExpenses.size(); x < y; x++){

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_title, null);        

            Expense expense = allDatesExpenses.get(x);

            TextView text = Font.useHandelGotic(this.context, (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleDate)) ;
    text.setText(expense.getDateExpense());  

            ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            ArrayList<Expense> expensesByDate = (ArrayList<Expense>) dataExpenses.getExpensesByDate(expense.getDateExpense());
            listview.setDivider(null);
            listview.setAdapter(new AdapterTransaction(this.context, expensesByDate));

            mainLayout.addView(view);

        }       
        return fragmentHistory;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you've given, I would guess that your `LinearLayout` is set to horizontal (the default), so all of your titles/listviews are actually being added but you can't see them because they're off the side.  Fix that by adding

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

to your `LinearLayout` XML tag.

If that's not the problem, then post the pertinent XML layouts please.

Comment: Thanks! It's incredible! Mi code was working all fine. That was the problem! The xml did not had the orientation. I putted it and all work as needed.